# Using multer in memory buffer with GraphicsMagick

Tags: node.js, express, graphicsmagick, multer

I'm trying to resize an image uploaded in memory, using multer over express to get the file. While I can access req.files.picture.buffer and it shows some content, when I pass the buffer to GM I receive a ENOENT. The code is as follows:

```
var buffer = req.files.picture.buffer

gm(buffer)
  .options({imageMagick: true})
  .resize(300)
  .toBuffer('PNG', function (err, buffer) {
    if (err) return handle(err);
      console.log('done!');
  });

return res.sendStatus(200);
```

Either using `toBuffer` or `write` as the output I get the same ENOENT. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [`gm` Buffer example](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm#buffers), you also need to supply a filename for the data. Example: `gm(buffer, 'foo.jpg')`

Comment: There was a problem with my machine, some env variables were causing trouble. Now it works. The second parameter ('foo.jpg') is not necessary when working on  streams/buffer.

Answer (score 0):

There was some problem with my Linux setup and ImageMagick was not available to Node.js. After re-configuring the machine the code works without changes.